# fancybox compatibility with Android native browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, fancybox

fancybox is working well on my site when seen on computer

but not working(i mean not getting overlays) on viewing in mobile(android native browser). I don't know what is the problem? is it a bug? please help me.

Comment: Tested it on Android 3.2.1 and Android 4.0.3 with native browser. It worked perfectly, using Fancybox 1.3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fancybox is not supported on mobile browsers, largely because it and similar scripts make heavy use of "position: fixed", which is not supported in Mobile Safari and the Android browser.

See: http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/c1535b2bdefcad58/507ec578bb5347fa

Comment: could you give any alternate solution for this